# How to see the readiness status of each container in a pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a pod with a normal python container and istio running as a side car. During a redeployment, I see that one container start fine, the other does not.

```
NAME                 READY   STATUS
my-pod-name-xyz      1/2     Running
```

The logs of both containers appear to be fine. In the description of the pod, I see the following event:

```
  Warning  Unhealthy  97s   kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://172.29.148.23:15021/healthz/ready": dial tcp 172.29.148.23:15021: connect: connection refused
```

How do I find out which container is failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ReadinessProbe for each container should be different, so you could see which is failing.

Also use

```
kubectl get pod <pod> -o yaml
```

and search for `containerStatuses`. There you can see the status of each container.